# How can I toggle only certain elements in a list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class='sidebar-listview ui-listview' data-role='listview' data-theme='c'>
      <li class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c ui-li-has-icon io-sidebar-section io-sidebar-section-collapsed io-sidebar-section-advanced-toggle' id='0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240'>
          <img src='/document/d5308dfc-af9e-41a4-ab0f-9b5ff6c4c43e/latest' class='ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb' height='16' width='16'/>
          <div class='io-sidebar-link-text'>Activities</div>
      </li>
      <span io-sidebar-section='0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240'>
          <li class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-d ui-li-has-icon io-sidebar-link io-sidebar-link-standard' data-theme='d' io-sidebar-section='0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240' io-object-view='/cms?url=ui/object&object=34029fec-b949-3780-b9e6-9522413b9f2c' io-record-view='/cms?url=ui/record&object=34029fec-b949-3780-b9e6-9522413b9f2c' style='display: block'>
              <img src='/document/140075b9-878e-4fc8-9ed6-ac422046accf/latest' class='ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb' height='16' width='16'/>
              <div class='io-sidebar-link-text'>Events</div>
          </li>
          <li class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-d ui-li-has-icon io-sidebar-link io-sidebar-link-standard' data-theme='d' io-sidebar-section='0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240' io-object-view='/cms?url=ui/object&object=db13a9ad-2494-34bb-8a59-cb99fd308051' io-record-view='/cms?url=ui/record&object=db13a9ad-2494-34bb-8a59-cb99fd308051' style='display: block'>
              <img src='/document/423fc17f-08b2-46bb-a1db-a5395cd63b83/latest' class='ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb' height='16' width='16'/>
              <div class='io-sidebar-link-text'>Tasks</div>
          </li>
          <li class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-d ui-li-has-icon io-sidebar-link io-sidebar-link-standard' data-theme='d' io-sidebar-section='0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240' io-object-view='/cms?url=ui/object&object=23505d2a-bf3b-11e0-8058-001ec93afa2c' io-record-view='/cms?url=ui/record&object=23505d2a-bf3b-11e0-8058-001ec93afa2c' style='display: block'>
              <img src='/document/f7cd2d4c-1bbe-4131-b1bb-b6bff1e9bea5/latest' class='ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb' height='16' width='16'/>
              <div class='io-sidebar-link-text'>Projects</div>
          </li>
          <li class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-d ui-li-has-icon io-sidebar-link io-sidebar-link-advanced' data-theme='d' io-sidebar-section='0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240' io-object-view='/cms?url=ui/object&object=5e0d648c-bf52-11e0-b7e6-001ec93afa2c' io-record-view='/cms?url=ui/record&object=5e0d648c-bf52-11e0-b7e6-001ec93afa2c' style='display: none'>
              <img src='/document/8dbc2454-a2f8-47b0-ba32-d5b8552c0160/latest' class='ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb' height='16' width='16'/>
              <div class='io-sidebar-link-text'>Milestones</div>
          </li>
      </span>
</div>
```

When I click on a section-header I want to toggle io-sidebar-link-advanced.

I have the jquery which doesn't work:

```
$('.io-sidebar-section-collapsed').click(function () {  
    console.log('section header clicked!');
    console.log($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().siblings('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').toggle('fast',function(){});
});
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').toggle('fast',function(){});
```

with:

```
$(this).parent().find('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').toggle('fast',function(){});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WqvLF/)

Comment: This is great! I have many "sections" how can I restrict this to only the particular section I'm clicking?

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).parent()` refers to the div, so you're selecting the div's siblings. Try `$(this).parent().find(...)` instead of `$(this).parent().siblings(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(this).parent().siblings('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').toggle('fast',function(){});
```

Needs to be

```
    $(this).siblings('span').children('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').toggle('fast',function(){});
```

The parent div has no siblings here.

Comment: Nice! This is great. How can I limit the toggle to only the section that is being clicked? I have many `io-sidebar-section-collapsed` and would like to only toggle the advanced links within a particular section.

Comment: I believe that should do it. Its limited by the use of `$(this)`. `$(this)` refers to the one of the multiple  `io-sidebar-section-collapsed` you may have clicked in your code, given that the `span` with sections in is always a sibling of your header `li`